# Why MEF does not discover my generic exports?

Tags: c#, generics, mef

I would like to consume a queue plugin using MEF. I've tried the following but the following fields queuePlugins and alternativeApproach, that are decorates with an Import attribute (in the following example) are empty
Any idea?
Thanks,
ATom

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MefIsHell
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            QueueFactory<string> qf = new QueueFactory<string>();
            var queue = qf.GetQueue(QueueProviderType.InProcess);
        }
    }

    public class QueueFactory<T> : IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification where T : class
    {
        [ImportMany]
        private IEnumerable<Lazy<IQueueProviderPlugin<T>, IQueuePluginMetadata>> queuePlugins = null;

        [ImportMany(typeof(IQueueProviderPlugin<>))]
        private IEnumerable<IQueueProviderPlugin<T>> alternativeApproach;

        public QueueFactory ()
        {
            ComposeMEF();
        }
        private void ComposeMEF()
        {
            var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
            CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            container.ComposeParts(this);
        }

        public void OnImportsSatisfied()
        {
            if (!queuePlugins.Any())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("queuePlugins is empty");
            }
            if (!alternativeApproach.Any())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("alternativeApproach is empty");
            }
        }

        public IQueueProviderPlugin<T> GetQueue(QueueProviderType QueueType)
        {
            var plugins = from lazyPlugin in queuePlugins
                          let metadata = lazyPlugin.Metadata
                          where metadata.QueueType == QueueType
                          select lazyPlugin.Value;

            if (plugins.Count() == 0)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("No plugins!!!");
            }

            return plugins.First();
        }
    }
    public interface IQueueProviderPlugin<T>
    {
        void Enqueue(T item);
        T Dequeue();
    }

    public enum QueueProviderType
    {
        InProcess,
        RabbitMQ
    }

    public interface IQueuePluginMetadata
    {
        QueueProviderType QueueType { get; }
    }

    [MetadataAttribute]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class QueueTypeAttribute : ExportAttribute, IQueuePluginMetadata
    {
        public QueueTypeAttribute(QueueProviderType QueueType)
            : base(typeof(IQueueProviderPlugin<>))
        {
            this.QueueType = QueueType;
        }

        public QueueProviderType QueueType { get; private set; }
    }

    [QueueTypeAttribute(QueueProviderType.InProcess)] // : ExportAttribute !!!
    [Export(typeof(IQueueProviderPlugin<>))]          // duplicate export
    public class InProcessQueuePlugin : IQueueProviderPlugin<string>
    {
        private Queue<string> _queue = new Queue<string>();

        public string Dequeue()
        {
            return _queue.Dequeue();
        }

        public void Enqueue(string item)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize queuePlugins?

Comment: I do not initialize queuePlugins directly, MEF should do that.

Comment: And it does, but it does not discover the exported plugin

Comment: @Atom Have you read through this article?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2010/07/13/how-to-debug-and-diagnose-mef-failures.aspx After you look at that, can you add to your question any output from Mefx that references your export, and the contents of `container` after composition occurs? Also, if you're using .NET 4.5, you could disable silent rejection as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8324747/1002306

Comment: Hi Matt, I've used MEFX and I see my exports. Also there is nothing unusual in the composition log plus, since I'm using .NET4.5 I've disable silent rejection as well and no error occurs.  I feel it's all about the type mapping.  I'm exporting IQueueProviderPlugin<T> using: [Export(typeof(IQueueProviderPlugin<>))] and importing the same using [ImportMany(typeof(IQueueProviderPlugin<>))].  BUT in the importing code, T is set to string  (QueueFactory<string> qf = new QueueFactory<string>();) and the mapping fails.  If I export <string> instead of <> the compsition works fine.

Comment: I would like to use the generics here and not add an export attribute for every new DTO I use, Very much like KnownType attribute of WCF.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

See an possible solution in
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02a2a0b9-0c3e-4ba1-a525-ffa3a140bae9/why-mef-does-not-discover-my-exports?forum=csharpgeneral
Please update if you have a better solution for the MEF Vs. Generics issue.
Regards,
ATom

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to export an open generic type when your object is not actually closed over that export. To export `IQueueProviderPlugin<string>`, use `[Export(typeof(IQueueProviderPlugin<string>))]` instead of `[Export(typeof(IQueueProviderPlugin<>))]`.

If you want to export `IQueueProviderPlugin<>` instead, then you have to make your export an open (unclosed) generic type:

```cs
[QueueTypeAttribute(QueueProviderType.InProcess)] // exports IQueueProviderPlugin<>
public class InProcessQueuePlugin<T> : IQueueProviderPlugin<T>
{
    readonly Queue<T> _queue = new Queue<T>();

    public T Dequeue() => _queue.Dequeue();

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(item);
    }
}
```