# SatisfyImportsOnce ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, mef

Stack Trace:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.DisposableReflectionComposablePart'.
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.DisposableReflectionComposablePart.EnsureRunning()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionComposablePart.System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ICompositionElement.get_Origin()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException.WriteElementGraph(StringBuilder writer, ICompositionElement element)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException.WriteError(StringBuilder writer, CompositionError error)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException.WritePath(StringBuilder writer, IEnumerable`1 path, Int32 ordinal)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException.WritePaths(StringBuilder writer, IEnumerable`1 paths)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException.BuildDefaultMessage()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException.get_Message()
```

From MSDN docs, I can see it does that exception when the Container is Disposed, but it was never `.Dispose()`'d.

Im using it to import the actual Form to add extra security from Cracking Attempts.

It's only occurring on a User's Windows Server 2008 <strike>(no idea if r2 or not)</strike> (Confirmed to be R2)
It has been proven to work with the same code on other users Server 2008 systems (RDP).

```
AggregateCatalog aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly));
CompositionContainer _container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog, true);
_container.ComposeExportedValue<ExportProvider>(_container);
_container.ComposeExportedValue(_container);
_container.ComposeExportedValue<ICompositionService>(_container);
Program program = new Program();
_container.SatisfyImportsOnce(program);
program._Run();
_container.Dispose();
```

The code above is exactly what im running and I can confirm its happening on SatisfyImportsOnce and not in _Run(); (Which requires an import)

Edit this is still occuring and I got the mdmp files from a user encountering the error, this time it was a user on Windows 7 SP1 and another on Windows 10 Latest. :/

Comment: Well, what code is running, what did you try and what is it all about cracking attempts? There's nothing to see for us.

Comment: how do you know it isn't disposed? this call stack is already a post-mortem stack, as the exception handler is trying to include as much information about the failure as it can. the root cause could be anything, try to figure out what throws the `CompositionException` at first, and show user code accordingly.

Comment: My bad, I added the code @Waescher

Comment: @dlatikay Well I added the code, which is exactly whats being run and as far as I can tell, its not being disposed.

Comment: this is a pain to debug, but [there are options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8324747/1132334). Found [this](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/28304781/), it calls `EnsureRunning` but why should it run when you're just about to populate the imports it will need to run!? no clue.

Comment: Still need this solved, I legit cannot find any reason for this code to fail :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The age old bug has been fixed!**

The reason was... CORRUPT REGISTRY ENTRIES.
Of all things haha.

Here's the fix:
Inside of CMD, type `lodctr /r`

This is a similar error to do with Perfomance Counters and they both have the exact same fix.

I found this out by looking at the Exceptions data, I looked at all the data like TargetSite, Source, Message e.t.c and somewhere it said the following:
`Indikatornamensdaten können nicht geladen werden, da ein ungültiger Index "" aus der Registrierung gelesen wurde.`

Which means briefly that an index in the registry was empty/missing. Did a bit of researching and the same error occurs with Performance Counters which I have already encountered before. So I applied to same fix and it was just like magic.

:) enjoy everyone tearing there hair out over this error! Good luck!